# If $Y \sim geometric(P)$ and $P \sim \mathcal B(2, 1)$ how to compute $E(Y)$ and marginal pmf of $Y$?

Tags: distributions, self-study, beta-distribution, marginal-distribution, geometric-distribution

$$Y \sim Geometric(P)\\
P \sim \mathcal B(2, 1)$$

I'm trying to compute $E[Y]$ without finding marginal distribution of $Y$.  I need some hints here.  I also need to find the pmf of $Y$.  My approach is as follows:

Integrate from 0, 1 over $p: f(p)(1-f(p))^{(y-1)}$  where $f(p)$ is the pdf of $\mathcal B(a, b)$.  This leads to some messy algebra.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: For the expected value of $Y$, use the [Law of Total Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: You should add the homework tag.

Comment: For the pmf of $Y$, look into the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: how does the law of total expectation apply in a context where there are no conditionals?

Comment: @fl4nders, Zen has answered your question. It's important to be precise about which random variable follows a given distribution. $Y|P=p$ is random and follows a Geometric distribution with parameter $p$. $Y$ is also a random variable but the problem has not specified its distribution.

Comment: @Max right--this is exactly how the problem was given, in its confusing state.  thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

About your comment:

"How does the law of total expectation apply in a context where there are no conditionals?".

You don't see the conditional distribution because a more precise statement of the problem is 
$$Y\mid P=p\sim \textrm{Geo}(p) \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad P\sim \textrm{Be}(2,1) \, .$$

Now that you see the conditional distribution, just do the integral: 
$$\textrm{E}[Y]=\int_0^1 \textrm{E}[Y\mid P=p]\,f(p)\,dp \, .$$

Similarly for the pmf: 
$$p(y)=\int_0^1 \textrm{Pr}(Y=y\mid P=p)\,f(p)\,dp \, .$$

This is all that you need.